# Why can't the malachim understand Aramaic?

Tags: language, aramaic

Why can't the malachim [understand](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.33a.6) Aramaic?
Does it have anything to do with the fact that it was the lingua franca of the jewish demographic of that time period?

Comment: Try https://oztorah.com/2012/04/do-the-angels-understand-aramaic/

Comment: The high ranking "palace" angels are probably too posh to speak anything other than Hebrew or interact with people. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_Judaism#Angelic_hierarchy

Comment: See Mishnah Berurah 101:18 that according to the opinion that only Aramaic is the problem, is because Aramaic is considered “lowly” in their eyes, and It’s explained because it is a distortion of Hebrew